# ACF Multiple Map Markers

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and want to pull in the field called 'location' to display some locations on a map. How would i adjust the following code to display multiple markers from my location field?

The format of the custom field is like so:

```
echo 'Location: ' . get_field('location');
```

outputs ...

Location: -33.890542,151.274856

Thanks for your help.

```
<div id="group-map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;display:none;   float:left;margin:0 0 30px 0;"></div>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('group-map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: you say _"display multiple markers from my location field"_ but then the example you give only contains one set of coordinates.  Do you expect the field to have lots of coordinates in it?  Or will you have multiple location fields for each marker you want to display?

Comment: This map will be inside a loop of upto 20 posts, each with their own location field. Hope that helps - thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about ACF  or how to read the contents of its fields. However assuming you can get that into a javascript string that looks like `var field = "-33.890542, 151.274856"`, you can then do `var coords = field.split(',');` to turn it into an array of the two values.  Then use `new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]))` to create the position for your marker.

Comment: I can't quite get my head around this, could you include a little excerpt witin the context of my code please?

Comment: Can you update your question with any code that shows the ACF location field please?

Comment: I have done this now - thanks for you help!

Comment: That looks like PHP... what does this look like in the HTML source of your page?

Comment: Location: -33.890542,151.274856

Comment: That's not HTML, that's just some text.  Is it being output in an `<input>` field, as the contents of a  `<p></p>`, as a `data-` attribute on a `<div>` or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom query and loop through all locations.

```
var locations = [
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $locations = new WP_Query($args);
        if($locations->have_posts()){
            while($locations->have_posts()){ the_post();
            $loc = get_field('location')
    ?>
     ['<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>', <?php echo $loc[0]; ?>, <?php echo $loc[1]; ?>],
    <?php } } ?>
]
```